# URL redirected to provides GET parameters with # (and not ?)

Tags: query-string, dropbox-api

According to the Dropbox API documentation, a GET to https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize will render the Dropbox authentication website, and upon authenticating will redirect the client to the specified redirect URI with the access token as a GET parameter. However, the URL redirected to provides its GET parameters with # (and not ?).

For example, if I do https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=foo&redirect_uri=https://www.httpsnow.org/, I will get https://www.httpsnow.org/#access_token=foo&token_type=bearer&uid=bar (note the presence of the **#** symbol and the lack of a **?** symbol at the start of the query string).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the OAuth 2 "token flow" (`response_type=token`). The token flow is designed mostly for mobile and JavaScript-based apps. As [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize) says:

> **Token flow**
>
> These parameters are passed in the URL fragment (after the # in the
>   URL):

It sounds like you want to use the "code flow" instead (`response_type=code`):

> **Code flow**
>
> These parameters are passed in the query string (after the ? in the
>   URL):

Comment: Can't believe I missed that in the documentation. Thanks!